# Operating on a Regular Expression before applying Pumping Lemma

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

When applying the *pumping lemma* to prove that a language is irregular, is it allowed to start by operating on the language to make applying the pumping lemma easier?

For example, when attempting to disprove:

```
L = {0^i 1^j | j <= i and i, j > 0}
```

Can I first reverse the language like so:

```
L = {1^j 0^i | j <= i and i, j > 0}
```

and reason that "if the language were regular, reversing (or performing any operation that's closed under regular languages) it wouldn't make it irregular," then continue to pump so that *j* must be greater than *i*?

Comment: Yes, so long as you prove that the transformation you're applying is closed. But also recall that pumping works in both directions: the string you choose can be pumped *down* to zero instead of just up, so for a language like this you should be able to prove its irregularity directly.